# Access atoms in the list and set values

Tags: elixir

If I have a list of atoms like this

```
[:slug, :title]
```

How can I assign values to the atoms inside the list like tuples

```
[{:slug, "some"}, {:title, "title"}]
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a list/map somewhere which says `:slug` should become `"some"` and `:title` should become `"title"`?

Comment: @Dogbert no .I meant direct insertion through some function if possible. manipulate the list like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to iterate through the list to find and update values. Here's how you'd do it with `for`:

```
defmodule A do
  def assoc(xs, key, value) do
    for x <- xs, do: if(x == key, do: {x, value}, else: x)
  end
end

[:slug, :title]
|> A.assoc(:slug, "some")
|> A.assoc(:title, "title")
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[slug: "some", title: "title"]
```

Note that `[slug: "some", title: "title"]` is the same as `[{:slug, "some"}, {:title, "title"}]`. Elixir prints a list of tuples where the first element is an atom like this.

```
iex(1)> [slug: "some", title: "title"] == [{:slug, "some"}, {:title, "title"}]
true
```

Comment: as always Thanks. :)

Comment: @mudasobwa I thought OP wants to replace a single value at a time, not zip two lists into a list of tuples.

Comment: It's not terribly clear that is a constraint--at least from reading the question. I'd say `zip` seems like a viable alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Enum.zip/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip/2)?

```rb
Enum.zip ~w|slug title|a, ~w|some title|
#⇒ [slug: "some", title: "title"]
```